# Как установить Ubuntu в MBR?

Tags: ubuntu, mbr, gpt

Во время установки Ubuntu 22.04 LTS начал просить GPT, а это подразумевало потерю данных диска и невозможность заново установить Shindows 7 в дальнейшем, а он нужен сестре. Если можно, то каким образом мне установить Ubuntu в диск с таблицей MBR? Или, может, подскажете, как создать расширенный раздел, в котором в свою очередь GPT, но при этом так, чтобы загрузчик и щинду видел. Есть кстати GParted Live, в идеале хотелось бы создать с его помощью.

Comment: `Или, может, подскажете, как создать расширенный раздел, в котором в свою очередь GPT` -- эм ... , правильно ли я понимаю что вы хотите в расширенном разделе таблицы разделов MBR создать таблицу разделов GPT ?

Comment: @Zt. Надежда была. У меня еще стоит Shindows 7 в дуалбуте (е**чий grub), может, посоветуете прогу для перехода с MBR на GPT?